# Pytest won't accept argument starting with ../../

Tags: python, cygwin, pytest

I have added a custom command line argument --dll but when I supply a path starting with ../../ it doesn't recognize the argument:

```
# pytest --dll ../../lib.dll
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --dll
```

However it works if I type "--dll=../../lib.dll", "--dll ../lib.dll" or put another argument before.

Why is this and is it pytest specific?

I'm running this from Cygwin with Cygwin's python.

Comment: The `--dll` argument is not part of `pytest` framework. Either it is defined in some plugin or in your local plugin, stored in a `conftest.py`. Please enhance your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

On windows, path separators are `\` not `/` -try `..\..\lib.dll`

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is run from Cygwin.